# refetchEvents not updating the calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

When I click the `<h1>`each time  with a new `balance` object calander.fullCalendar('refetchEvents') is not refreshed.So month is not changed in calendar view.

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
     app .controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

      $scope.init=function(){
      $scope.LeaveBalance=[
            {
                'month':"JAN",
                'pd':06,
                'op':04,
                'defaultDate':'2017-01-05'
            },
            {
                'month':"FEB",               
                'pd':06,
                'op':04,
                'defaultDate':'2017-02-05'
            },
            {
                'month':"MAR",
                'pd':06,
                'op':04,
                'defaultDate':'2017-03-05'
            },           
            {
                'month':"DEC",
                'pd':06,
                'op':04,
                'defaultDate':'2017-12-05'
            }          

        ];
      }

      $scope.myfunc =function(balance){      
          $scope.showLeaveBalance(balance)      
      }   

             $scope.showLeaveBalance =function(balance){
            calendar= $('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: balance.defaultDate,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            events: [
                 {
                     title: 'SL',
                    start: '2017-10-01',
                   // specialevent:'2017-10-15'
                },              
                {                   
                    title: 'SL',
                    start: '2017-10-28',
                     //specialevent:'2017-10-18'
                 }
            ]
           });    
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents')

      }

      }])
```

my fiddle is not working https://jsfiddle.net/shwwL2z1/2/ But I have updated everyting correctly.Can anyone check it?

Comment: your fiddle is not working

Comment: yes its displaying `moment is not defined` error. but I added moment plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution:

```
 $('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: balance.defaultDate,
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            //weekends:false,
            events: [
                {
                    title: balance.title,
                    start: balance.startDate,
                   // specialevent:'2017-10-15'
                },              
                {                   
                    title: balance.title,
                    start: balance.startDate,
                    //specialevent:'2017-10-18'
                }
            ]
        });      
         $('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', balance.defaultDate);
```

By adding `$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', balance.defaultDate);` can update date,month and year.

Answer (score 0):

```
      $scope.myfunc =function(balance){
          //Removes events from the calendar.
          uiCalendarConfig.calendars.calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents'); 
          $scope.showLeaveBalance(balance)      
      }
```

for more details [click](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEvents/) here.

Comment: what is `uiCalendarConfig` here?